# Sql need to sum column several times and break result in one row horizontally

Tags: sql

SQL needed to sum column several times and break result in one row by store horizontally, but I'm getting null rows mixed with totals need to take them out
Query:

```
 SELECT distinct IdPurch, 
  Datediff(week, (dateadd(day,-1, '2021-01-03')), '2021-01-09') AS wks,
  (Select sum(WgtSold)   where   store = '000001'  ) as lam,
  (Select sum(WgtSold)   where   store = '000002') as Riv  
  FROM [LAHAMARK].[dbo].[itemSale]
  LEFT OUTER Join [BRdata].[dbo].[Item]  on [LAHAMARK].[dbo].[itemSale].UPC15 = [BRdata].[dbo].[Item].[UPC]  
  LEFT OUTER join [BRdata].[dbo].[ItemMovement] on [LAHAMARK].[dbo].[itemSale].UPC15 = [BRdata].[dbo].[ItemMovement].[UPC]    
  where  Date  between   '2021-01-03' and  '2021-01-03'  and   idPurch = '1018'
  group by IdPurch,Store
```

query Result  :

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: 2) You (rarely) never combine `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`, since GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select IdPurch, 
       sum(case when store = '000001' then WgtSold end) as lam,
       sum(case when store = '000002' then WgtSold end) as Riv  
from [LAHAMARK].[dbo].[itemSale] its join
     [BRdata].[dbo].[Item] i
     on its.UPC15 = i.[UPC] join
     [BRdata].[dbo].[ItemMovement] im
     on its.UPC15 = im.[UPC]    
where Date  between '2021-01-03' and '2021-01-03'  and
      idPurch = 1018
group by IdPurch ;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query much easier to write and to read.
- The week calculation is superfluous for only one week and has nothing really to do with the gist of the question, so I removed it.
- There is no need to aggregate by `store`.  You don't want a separate row for each `store`.
- I removed the single quotes around `1018`.  It looks like a number and ids typically are numbers.  If it is a string, definitely include the single quotes, though.

Comment: Thank you so much, I truly appreciate your input, it works  greatly appreciated